# Adding a dialog on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

[image]

I am creating a visualforce page and  i want to add a dialog with the available values and another dialog that contains selected values and need two arrows between these dialogs to add and remove values like below image

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this [Multiselect Picklist Visualforce Component](https://github.com/metadaddy/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist) that you can add to your code base. It is configurable e.g.:

```
<c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Contacts"
    leftOptions="{!allContacts}"
    rightLabel="Selected Contacts"
    rightOptions="{!selectedContacts}"
    size="14"
    width="150px"/>
```

and provides this user interface:

[image: screen shot]

If you want to, you can modify e.g. the style of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

[Dueling Picklist](http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/dueling-picklist/) of SLDS is also worth looking.

> A dueling-picklist is used to move options between two lists and is
>   often referred to as a multi-select. Sometimes, the list options can
>   then be re-ordered, depending on the use case.

**Code**:

```
<div class="slds-form-element" role="group" aria-labelledby="picklist-group-label">
  <div id="picklist-group-label" class="slds-form-element__label slds-form-element__legend slds-text-title_caps">Select Options</div>
  <div class="slds-dueling-list">
    <div class="slds-assistive-text" id="drag-live-region" aria-live="assertive"></div>
    <div class="slds-assistive-text" id="option-drag-label">Press space bar when on an item, to move it within the list. CMD plus left and right arrow keys, to move items between lists.</div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
      <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="label-83">First Category</span>
      <div class="slds-dueling-list__options">
        <ul aria-describedby="option-drag-label" aria-labelledby="label-83" aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="listbox">
          <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
            <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
              <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 1">Option 1</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
            <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
              <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 2">Option 2</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
            <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
              <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 3">Option 3</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
            <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
              <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 6">Option 6</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection to Second Category">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#right"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection to Second Category</span>
      </button>
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection to First Category">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#left"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection to First Category</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
      <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="label-84">Second Category</span>
      <div class="slds-dueling-list__options">
        <ul aria-describedby="option-drag-label" aria-labelledby="label-84" aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="listbox">
          <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
            <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
              <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 4">Option 4</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
            <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="-1">
              <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 5">Option 5</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection Up">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#up"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection Up</span>
      </button>
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Move Selection Down">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection Down</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Design**:

[image: Dueling Picklist]